# set interval function not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Hi all this is my code where time interval function not working it works before but now its not working can't find the exact reason for this issue i have checked other script function included in the same page no issue in that

kindly Suggest me the possible ways to check the other problems  me to solve it

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    setInterval(function(){ 

        alert("Hello"); 

    }, 3000);


</script>
```

my console look like this

```
Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# insteadjquery-1.10.2.min.js:1
ReferenceError: exports is not defined
sweetalert.js:5:1
Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead.jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5:11337
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5:17117
TypeError: t.css(...) is undefined
jquery.flot.min.js:28:4583
PJAX loaded!visitors:418:5
Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# insteadjquery-1.10.2.min.js:1
ReferenceError: exports is not defined
sweetalert.js:5:1
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.jquery-1.10.2.min.js:5:17117
```

Comment: The code is perfectly alright. Any errors on console?

Comment: Do you have any extra code in this script section?

Comment: I have removed all the codes from the script now my script contains only the above code @AliSheikhpour

Comment: i have posted my console there @RajaprabhuAravindasamy

Comment: But it did work for me? http://jsbin.com/koguqe/edit?js,console

Comment: Maybe setInterval is working but you dont see the alert because there is an error with sweetalert.js, replace alert("hallo"); with console.log("hello"); and try again

Comment: @chris     You are right. However, console.log("Hello") will still not make any difference if there is an Error that is stopping Script Execution. (@)vimalmkumar:: Would you mind commenting out all the external JS Libraries except for JQuery and Test again? The Issue is from one the loaded Libraries.... most likely (like chris noted) the **sweetalert.js**

Comment: try closing and opening the browser again! you might set the browser to prevent more alerts from this page!

Comment: @AliSheikhpour   There's already an Error on Line 5 of ***sweetalert.js*** that is stopping Javascript Execution... Nothing would be different till that Error is addressed and fixed...

Comment: Have you loaded the jquery in head area https://blog.jquery.com/2016/04/05/jquery-1-12-3-and-2-2-3-released/

Comment: @wolfgang1983    His Code would work very smoothly without JQuery, anyways. The Problem is neither with his Code nor JQuery but with the **sweetalert.js** File. ***There's already an Error on Line 5 of sweetalert.js*** that is stopping Javascript Execution... ***And nothing would be different till that Error is addressed and fixed.***

Comment: get the latest sweetalert which you clearly don't have because there's no reference to `exports` on line 5 of the current 11 month old release

Comment: hi guys its the problem with the browser the function working fine in chrome only in firefox browser it not working..whats the reason?? can any one have suggestion for this

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with this code, it's perfectly fine. As we can see in the console error sweetalert.js file has some issue and getting error, which in turn blocking the javascript execution.

To make us help you better, either post your sweetalert.js file also here so we can see what's wrong with that file and update your question as current question doesn't holds true.